# Redirecting a single request to another pages, ignoring www subdomain

Tags: iis-7.5, redirect, subdomain

I have a site running on IIS 7.5 that does an automatic redirect from 'http://mysite.com/whatever.aspx' to 'http://www.mysite.com/whatever.aspx'

On the site, there is a lot of traffic to an old URL that I want to redirect to the front page, index.aspx: 'http://mysite.com/foo/bar/index.cgi%something=asdf&somethingelse=qwerty'

The problem is that no matter what I try, I can only get the redirect to work with the www subdomain. If I use the URL without www, I just end up at 'http://www.mysite.com/404.aspx'

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance for all help!

Edit3: it seems like the browser caching the redirect response was messing with me, so edit2 is wrong. See my response below.

Edit2: disregard edit1, it doesn't seem like it's working after all.

Edit: here's some further info: using [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313074) I've managed to redirect from 'http://mysite.com/foo/bar/index.cgi' to 'http://www.mysite.com/index.aspx', but if I add the query string parameters, it still redirects to 'http://www.mysite.com/404.aspx'

Isn't there a way to catch all requests to the cgi file, including query string parameters?

Answer (score 2):

So, I managed to get it working in the following way:

1) Add the subdirectory /foo/bar to the application in IIS
2) Add the file index.cgi in the subdirectory
3) Create the following webconfig in the subdirectory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpRedirect enabled="true"  exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent">
      <add wildcard="*.cgi*" destination="http://www.mysite.com/index.aspx" />
    </httpRedirect>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

That catches **all** requests to index.cgi, but that works for me. I could probably have gotten it to work with just the URL I specified over, but it's not needed.

Comment: You could use **URL Rewrite module** and do all this without creating folders/index.cgi -- http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/664/using-url-rewrite-module-20/